# App Crashes when reloadData() gets called in a custom SelfSizedTableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit, reloaddata

I’m having a crash happens when `reloadData()` gets called in a custom `SelfSizedTableView` ,
any idea why? and how to resolve it?

SelfSizedTableView:

```swift
import UIKit

open class SelfSizedTableView: UITableView {
    open override func reloadData() {
        super.reloadData()
        self.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
    }

    open override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        setNeedsLayout()
        layoutIfNeeded()
        return CGSize(
            width: contentSize.width,
            height: contentSize.height
        )
    }
}
```

Stacktrace:

```text
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  CoreAutoLayout                 0x17d38 object_table_insert_and_return_old_value_if_replaced + 96
1  CoreAutoLayout                 0x8324 NSISObjectTableInsert + 72
2  CoreAutoLayout                 0x80b0 -[NSISEngine startObservingChangesForVariable:] + 76
3  UIKitCore                      0x373e2c _UILayoutItemSetUpVariableObservation + 144
4  UIKitCore                      0x2aae18 _UILayoutItemCreateAndObserveVariableWithValueRestriction + 104
5  UIKitCore                      0x518fc4 -[UIView nsli_boundsWidthVariable] + 48
6  UIKitCore                      0x34b7e8 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) nsli_lowerAttribute:intoExpression:withCoefficient:forConstraint:onBehalfOfLayoutGuide:] + 2860
7  UIKitCore                      0x566e50 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) nsli_lowerAttribute:intoExpression:withCoefficient:forConstraint:] + 316
8  CoreAutoLayout                 0xbb50 -[NSLayoutConstraint _lowerIntoExpression:reportingConstantIsRounded:] + 76
9  CoreAutoLayout                 0xdee8 -[NSLayoutConstraint _addToEngine:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:] + 136
10 UIKitCore                      0x1cd270 __57-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:]_block_invoke_2 + 368
11 CoreAutoLayout                 0x7bac -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] + 80
12 UIKitCore                      0x1badd0 __57-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:]_block_invoke + 528
13 UIKitCore                      0x3980f4 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:] + 188
14 UIKitCore                      0x1cd1b8 __57-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:]_block_invoke_2 + 184
15 CoreAutoLayout                 0x7bac -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] + 80
16 UIKitCore                      0x1badd0 __57-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:]_block_invoke + 528
17 UIKitCore                      0x3980f4 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:] + 188
18 UIKitCore                      0x1cd1b8 __57-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:]_block_invoke_2 + 184
19 CoreAutoLayout                 0x7bac -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] + 80
20 UIKitCore                      0x1badd0 __57-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:]_block_invoke + 528
21 UIKitCore                      0x3980f4 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:] + 188
22 UIKitCore                      0x45ae68 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _initializeHostedLayoutEngine] + 208
23 UIKitCore                      0x1da868 -[UIView _layoutEngine_windowDidChange] + 120
24 UIKitCore                      0x29ebbc -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 276
25 UIKitCore                      0x29ee48 -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 928
26 UIKitCore                      0x1cb998 __45-[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:]_block_invoke + 136
27 CoreAutoLayout                 0x7bac -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] + 80
28 UIKitCore                      0x2576e4 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:] + 780
29 UIKitCore                      0x179ca4 -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] + 2148
30 UIKitCore                      0x38ec30 -[UITableView _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] + 104
31 UIKitCore                      0x168d68 -[UIScrollView _addContentSubview:atBack:] + 376
32 UIKitCore                      0x18d4e8 -[UITableView _addContentSubview:atBack:] + 248
33 UIKitCore                      0x189e70 __53-[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:]_block_invoke + 1744
34 UIKitCore                      0x1632d0 +[UIView(Animation) performWithoutAnimation:] + 96
35 UIKitCore                      0x3f4664 -[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:] + 244
36 UIKitCore                      0x27010c -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:] + 1916
37 UIKitCore                      0x45a858 -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsForRanges:createIfNecessary:] + 700
38 UIKitCore                      0x293f04 -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:] + 1464
39 UIKitCore                      0x16c484 -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 436
40 UIKitCore                      0x17c1d0 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 2556
41 QuartzCore                     0x3d520 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 528
42 UIKitCore                      0x1dd8b0 -[UIView(Hierarchy) layoutBelowIfNeeded] + 556
43 Drops                          0x78e68 SelfSizedTableView.reloadData() + 15 (SelfSizedTableView.swift:15)
44 Drops                          0x78eb8 @objc SelfSizedTableView.reloadData() + 4365668024 (<compiler-generated>:4365668024)
45 UIKitCore                      0x16c300 -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 48
46 UIKitCore                      0x17c1d0 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 2556
47 QuartzCore                     0x3d520 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 528
48 UIKitCore                      0x1dd8b0 -[UIView(Hierarchy) layoutBelowIfNeeded] + 556
49 Drops                          0x78f6c SelfSizedTableView.intrinsicContentSize.getter + 19 (SelfSizedTableView.swift:19)
50 Drops                          0x78ef4 @objc SelfSizedTableView.intrinsicContentSize.getter + 4365668084 (<compiler-generated>:4365668084)
51 UIKitCore                      0x19cae8 -[UIView _generateContentSizeConstraints] + 56
52 UIKitCore                      0x24beac -[UIView _updateContentSizeConstraints] + 268
53 UIKitCore                      0x2f6440 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateSystemConstraints] + 124
54 UIKitCore                      0x35aaac -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _sendUpdateConstraintsIfNecessaryForSecondPass:] + 480
55 UIKitCore                      0x17f5a0 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededCollectingViews:forSecondPass:] + 996
56 UIKitCore                      0x17f480 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededCollectingViews:forSecondPass:] + 708
57 UIKitCore                      0x17f480 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededCollectingViews:forSecondPass:] + 708
58 CoreAutoLayout                 0x7bac -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] + 80
59 UIKitCore                      0x4f6720 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _recursiveUpdateConstraintsIfNeededCollectingViews:forSecondPass:] + 120
60 UIKitCore                      0x17f480 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededCollectingViews:forSecondPass:] + 708
61 UIKitCore                      0x1e494c __100-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededWithViewForVariableChangeNotifications:]_block_invoke + 84
62 UIKitCore                      0x25c954 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededWithViewForVariableChangeNotifications:] + 160
63 UIKitCore                      0x314fd8 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:withHorizontalFittingPriority:verticalFittingPriority:hasIntentionallyCollapsedHeight:] + 224
64 UIKitCore                      0x272668 -[UITableViewCell systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:withHorizontalFittingPriority:verticalFittingPriority:] + 656
65 UIKitCore                      0x331148 -[UITableView _heightForCell:atIndexPath:] + 400
66 UIKitCore                      0x18a120 __53-[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:]_block_invoke + 2432
67 UIKitCore                      0x1632d0 +[UIView(Animation) performWithoutAnimation:] + 96
68 UIKitCore                      0x3f4664 -[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:] + 244
69 UIKitCore                      0x27010c -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:] + 1916
70 UIKitCore                      0x44a10c -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForRowAtIndexPath:willDisplay:] + 88
71 UIKitCore                      0x534d90 -[UITableView _heightForRowAtIndexPath:] + 152
72 UIKitCore                      0x1cab54 -[UISectionRowData heightForRow:inSection:canGuess:] + 208
73 UIKitCore                      0x16ee8c -[UITableViewRowData heightForRow:inSection:canGuess:adjustForReorderedRow:] + 252
74 UIKitCore                      0x237c54 -[UITableViewRowData rectForRow:inSection:heightCanBeGuessed:] + 332
75 UIKitCore                      0x16c890 -[UITableViewRowData rectForGlobalRow:heightCanBeGuessed:] + 108
76 UIKitCore                      0x277eb0 -[UITableView _prefetchCellAtGlobalRow:aboveVisibleRange:] + 264
77 UIKitCore                      0x1c52f4 __48-[UITableView _configureCellPrefetchingHandlers]_block_invoke + 56
78 UIKitCore                      0x170804 -[_UITableViewPrefetchContext updateVisibleIndexRange:withContentOffset:] + 2392
79 UIKitCore                      0x42db08 -[UITableView _updateCycleIdleUntil:] + 188
80 UIKitCore                      0x17e2b8 ___UIUpdateCycleNotifyIdle_block_invoke + 704
81 libdispatch.dylib              0x63094 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
82 libdispatch.dylib              0x64094 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
83 libdispatch.dylib              0x45858 _dispatch_main_queue_drain + 888
84 libdispatch.dylib              0x454d0 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$armv81 + 36
85 CoreFoundation                 0x4e0d4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
86 CoreFoundation                 0xb5f8 __CFRunLoopRun + 2544
87 CoreFoundation                 0x1e250 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 572
88 GraphicsServices               0x1988 GSEventRunModal + 160
89 UIKitCore                      0x4e5a94 -[UIApplication _run] + 1080
90 UIKitCore                      0x27efd4 UIApplicationMain + 336
91 libswiftUIKit.dylib            0x27ee4 UIApplicationMain(_:_:_:_:) + 100
92 Drops                          0x1249a0 static UIApplicationDelegate.main() + 4366371232 (<compiler-generated>:4366371232)
93 Drops                          0x124928 static AppDelegate.$main() + 25 (<compiler-generated>:25)
94 Drops                          0x1263e8 main + 26 (AppDelegate.swift:26)
95 ???                            0x1036b44d0 (Missing)
```

Comment: why don't you give the data source to the tableView?

Comment: Quick test --- no crashes. You need to provide more detail about what you're doing, when you're calling `reloadData()`, what else might be going on, etc. See [mre].

Comment: @JoiceGeorge this is just a subclass of the UITableView to override these two functions to make the tableview resizable.

Comment: @DonMag so this crash is not reproducible, and users affected are less %0.5 of the total and it happens only with the `SelfSizedTableView` subclass so I figure out it might be something with the overridden function implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Update your tableView in main thread. Ui should be always executed in main thread

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
    self.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Comment: This crash rarely happens and I definitely have the function called on the main thread.

Comment: Okay if you are doing any UI modification do it in main same problem I was also facing and It was also not crashing for me every time but with I checked all the UI-related modifications I added main thread now it never crashes for me